# Does exporting a Collection Cert from Azure Key Vault let you use a secure string? It does for a sever cert

Tags: azure, powershell, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault

I can create an object go through the process to pull my certificate from key vault and save it as a file.

```
 $certObject = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 -argumentlist $certToBytes,$null, "Exportable, PersistKeySet"
```

When I save my object without using Collection, I can use a secure string type when I export it.

```
$CertPw = $CertPw | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$protectedCertificateBytes = $certObject.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12,$CertPw )
```

When I open the pfx file, I can use the plain text that I converted to a secure string. BUT when I save it as a Collection, the plain text throws an error if I use it as a secure string. Is there any way to keep using it as a secure string? It works if it's just a regular string being used.

```
$certCollection = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details what kind of error your are getting and where ? I have tried using the -ASPlainText for X509Certificate2Collection and it worked fine for me.